# Store Nuxt 3 Does not update Store.Variable

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I cannot make my store work like I want.
I know how to do a store using vue 3 but with Nuxt 3 my value does not update etc

My Function To add something to the store:

```js
<script setup>
  function addWeight() {
    setters.setWeights(state(), {weight : weightInput.value, date : new Date().getTime()})
  }
<script/>
```

My Store :

```js
export const state = () => ({
    weights: []
})

export const getters = {
    getWeights(state){
        return state.weights;
    }
}

export const setters = {
    setWeights(state, {weight , date}) {
        state.weights.push({
            weight, date
        });
    }
}

export const actions = {
    async fetchWeights(state) {
        const res = { data : [64, 67, 79, 70, 100, 123, 23]};
        state.weights = res.data;
        return res.data;
    }
}
```

state.weight or getters.getWeights(state) always return []

Comment: You could just use existing solutions like https://pinia.vuejs.org/

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash npm install pinia @pinia/nuxt --legacy-peer-deps`

store/index.ts file:

```js
import {defineStore} from "pinia";

interface weightInterface {
        weight: number;
        date: string;
}

export const useStore = defineStore({
    id: 'store',
    state : () => ({
        weights : Array<weightInterface>()
    }),
    getters : {
        getWeights(): weightInterface[]{
            return this.weights;
        },
        getDateWeights(): weightInterface[] {
            //sort by date
            this.weights.sort((weight1, weight2) => +weight1.date - +weight2.date);
            //from 1238173458 to 09/23/2022
            for (let i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++){
                this.weights[i].date = new Date(this.weights[i].date).toLocaleDateString();
            }
            return this.weights;
        }
    },
    actions : {
        addWeight(weight: number, date: string): void {
            const newWeight: weightInterface = { weight : weight,date: date};
            this.weights.push(newWeight);
        }
    }
});
```

Works like a charm